# Can I use Glimpse with a .net 2.0 or 3.5 project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, glimpse

According to their [NuGet page](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Glimpse), Glimpse is for ASP.net 4.0. But is it possible to use it with 2.0 or 3.5?

I tried with a 2.0 project and got this error :

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Glimpse.Core' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built
>   by a runtime newer than the currently
>   loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 2.0 to 3.5 all use the 2.0 CLR, but 4.0 does not. As such, an assembly compiled using .NET 4.0 can only be loaded by the 4.0 CLR.

You could try getting the source and recompiling it using .NET 2.0 and naturally hoping they don't use any .NET 4 features (however, looking at the project description, I doubt it).

They have a GitHub repo is there: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse

Comment: Don't even waste your time in trying to recompile Glimpse source code on .NET 3.5. It depends on ASP.NET MVC 3, so you will need to first recompile ASP.NET MVC 3 for .NET 3.5 which could be a monumental work. So the simple answer is `no .NET 4.0` => `no Glimpse for you`.

Comment: @Darin I would agree about it being a large undertaking, but there is a version for webforms without the MVC part

Comment: The Glimpse team is looking at the possibility of adding support for older versions of the framework.  Vote for this at http://getglimpse.uservoice.com/

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Also there is Glimpse and Glimpse.MVC3. Glimpse has no dependency on MVC 3. Originally it was but as of a couple of months ago now it was split up to help pave the way for non MVC3 initiates.